# How to synchronise ajax and non-ajax code paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

So I've got this basket functionality where you enter, say, an author's name and it lists the available books.  You select what you want and then you can click to select another author.  When you do, you get a list looking roughly like this:

```
Stephen King                                 
       The Stand                             [remove]
       The Talisman                          [remove]
       Pet Sematary                          [remove]

Terry Pratchett
       Mort                                  [remove]
       Guards Guards                         [remove]
```

In the example above, the Stephen King books have been stored in Session, the Terry Pratchett books have not.  If I click the remove button on a Pratchett book, some jquery will just hide those.  If I remove a Stephen King book, an ajax request is triggered to remove it from Session before jquery hides it.

So my javascript looks something like this:

```
$('.book-remove').click(removeBook);

function deleteFromBasket(bookId) {
    var ajaxArgs = { BookId : bookId };
    return $.ajax({
        // blah blah, no problems here
        success: function(e) {
            hideRow();
        }
    });
}

function hideRow(bookId) {
        $('.book-id-' + bookId).hide();
}

function removeBook(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('needs-ajax-call') {
        var promise = deleteFromBasket($(this).prop("id").replace("book-id-", ""));

        // this is the problem.  how do I wait here for the ajax to complete?
    }
    else
        hideRow();

    // if i put promise.done(hideRow) up there, it still runs this too soon.
    doMoreStuff();
}
```

Comment: add the doMoreStuff() as a callback to the promise. Then put the doMoreStuff in the else case as well

Comment: Before anybody mentions it, don't do async:false, it's not well supported across browsers.

Comment: Have you tried $.when done?

Comment: You should never do `async: false` for this type of operation anyway.

Comment: @artm - `$.when()` has no magic powers.  All it does is tell you when one or more promises are done.  I don't see how it will help you here.  If you only have one promise, it is not needed.  It is useful when you want to know when multiple promises are done, but that situation isn't in play here.

Comment: Use `promise.done(doMoreStuff)` instead of `promise.done(hideRow)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to the question plus some suggestions for tidier DOM/javascript.

First, let's make sure that :

- the "session" entries are in static container(s) (eg a `<div>`) with `class="sessionResultsWrapper"`
- the "non session" entries are in static container(s) (eg a `<div>`) with `class="otherResultsWrapper"`
- each entry is an element (eg an `<li>`) with `class="entry"` and `data-bookID="xxxx"`

Now you are in a better position :

- to select elements without the need for cumbersome id parsing
- to establish a click handler that will fire on all existing "remove" buttons and any that are added later to the static containers.

```js
$(".sessionResultsWrapper, .otherResultsWrapper").on('click', '.book-remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        promise;
    if ($this.parents(".sessionResultsWrapper").length) {
        promise = deleteFromBasket($this.closest('entry').data('bookID'));
    } else {
        promise = $.when();//this is the most compact syntax for a resolved promise
    });

    // At this point, you have a promise regardless of whether a "session" or "non-session" button was clicked.
    // The only difference is that a "non-session" promise will be already resolved, while a "session" promise will be resolved later.
    // Because of the way promises work, we can simply chain a .then(fn), which will fire immediately (non session, Terry Pratchett title) or later (when ajax successfully returns, Stephen King title).

    promise.then(function() {
        $this.closest(".entry").hide();//or, if the entry will never be re-shown then .remove()
        doMoreStuff();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can structure all your code (both code paths with and without ajax) to use promises.  The code that doesn't have to do an ajax call can just start with a promise that is already resolved and both code paths will execute the same sequence (one will be faster to execute because it doesn't have to wait for the ajax call), but both will execute things in the same order:

Any stuff you want done AFTER the ajax call simply has to be moved into the `promise.then()` handler:

```
function removeBook(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var promise;

    if ($(this).hasClass('needs-ajax-call') {
        promise = deleteFromBasket($(this).prop("id").replace("book-id-", ""));
    }  else {
        // get an already resolved promise since no ajax call is required
        promise = $.Deferred().resolve();
    }
    // you can return this promise if you want the calling code 
    // to be able to know when you're done with everything
    return promise.then(function() {
        hideRow(bookId);    // assumes you've calculated a bookId somewhere
        doOtherStuff();
    });
}
```

This has the advantage that the lions share of your code is in one code path rather than two separate code paths and it solves your issue because all the code in the `.then()` handler will not execute until after the ajax call is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the doMoreStuff as a callback to the promise. 
Something like this

```
function removeBook(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('needs-ajax-call') {
        var promise = deleteFromBasket($(this).prop("id").replace("book-id-", ""));
        promise.done(doMoreStuff);
    }
    else{
        hideRow();
        doMoreStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `hideRow()` in the first case?